# JavaScript partial match on two arrays (one nested and one flat) should return true if any match exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I need to do a partial match through each node of a given array "results". The match will need to parse through every string separated by a space in the original input field. The following is the sample a my basic need. **And Please no Plugins**

I have two sets of arrays a results list array and a input field array given that:

If Input Search Term: "ABC pa 2014" - which right now I'm storing in an Array so I can use indexOf. However, it's matching full string of each space separated term.

Results List Array:

```
[
  {
    "sIndex": 0,
    "sItem": {
      "cName": "ABC Partners",
      "cId": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "sIndex": 1,
    "sItem": {
      "cName": "ABC Partners",
      "cId": 0,
      "pName": "[ABC] ABC Description",
      "pTick": "ABC",
      "pId": 0,
      "dName": "[2014] ABC Db",
      "dYear": [
        "2014"
      ],
      "dId": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "sIndex": 2,
    "sItem": {
      "cName": "ABC Partners",
      "cId": 0,
      "pName": "[ABC] ABC Description Two",
      "pTick": "ABC",
      "pId": 0,
      "dName": "[2014] ABC Db",
      "dYear": [
        "2014"
      ],
      "dId": 0
    }
  },
```

Full array for testing purposes:

```
[{"sIndex":0,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0}},{"sIndex":1,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0}},{"sIndex":2,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] ABC Partners DB","dYear":"2009","dId":0}},{"sIndex":3,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 1 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":1}},{"sIndex":4,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 1 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":2}},{"sIndex":5,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 2 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":3}},{"sIndex":6,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 2 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":4}},{"sIndex":7,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 3 BaseDB","dYear":"2009","dId":5}},{"sIndex":8,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 3 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":6}},{"sIndex":9,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 3 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":7}},{"sIndex":10,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 4 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":8}},{"sIndex":11,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 4 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":9}},{"sIndex":12,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 5 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":10}},{"sIndex":13,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 5 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":11}},{"sIndex":14,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2010] Scenario 6 DB","dYear":"2010","dId":12}},{"sIndex":15,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2010] Scenario 6 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2010","dId":13}},{"sIndex":16,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 7 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":14}},{"sIndex":17,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 7 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":15}},{"sIndex":18,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 8 BaseDB","dYear":"2009","dId":16}},{"sIndex":19,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 8 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":17}},{"sIndex":20,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 8 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":18}}]
```

The function should return the 2nd and third node.

and if Input Search Term: "ABC pa" the function should return all three nodes.

I apologize for the brevity of this question, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you comparing the search input to? cName or pName? Since the first fresult doesn't have a pName and the 2nd and 3rd results only have '2014' in their pName but the second doesn't contain 'Partners'. So I can't figure out how you want to match 'ABC pa 2014' to the 2nd and 3rd record.

Comment: Why does `"ABC pa 2014"` match the second and third, but not the first?

Comment: Supposedly since 2014 isn't in it, but I'm assuming there's a bug in the question atm.

Comment: A very naive solution: [`\{[^{}]*ABC[^{}]*pa[^{}]*2014[^{}]*}`](https://regex101.com/r/lD9lL8/1). But I guess you will need to use JSON parser.

Comment: @shilly, apologies I've updated the JSON. I would like to match first: cName and dYear, if this doesn't exist I would like to match pTick and dYear. Then after that I'd like to match by any given permutation. After returning the second and third, I would then return  the third (and or rest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Steps

- Split your search input by spaces into an array of words.
- Use the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter the source array.
- Loop through the properties of the `sItem` property of each item of the source array and:

  - See if the property is a `String` and if true

    - Loop through the searched words to see if they are found in that property
- If all the words were found in the properties, return true to the `filter` method

#### Code

```
function search(val) {
  val = val.split(' '); // Step 1
  var filtered = arr.filter(function(item) { // Step 2
    var found = []; // Array to save how many words were found
    for (var prop in item.sItem) { // Step 3
      if (typeof item.sItem[prop] === 'string') { // Step 3.1
        for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { // Step 3.1.1
          // Look if the current property has any of the words of the search input
          if (item.sItem[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(val[i].toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            found[i] = true; // if found, save to the found array
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // if the true values of the found array has the same length of the input search array
    return found.filter(function(expr) { return expr; }).length == val.length; // Step 4
  });

  // sort the filtered array by the dName property and return it
  return filtered.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.sItem.dName > a.sItem.dName;
  });
}
```

#### See it working below

```js
(function(d) {
  d.getElementById('search').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    var result = search(this.value);
    d.querySelector('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
  });

  var arr = [{"sIndex":0,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0}},{"sIndex":1,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0}},{"sIndex":2,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] ABC Partners DB","dYear":"2009","dId":0}},{"sIndex":3,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 1 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":1}},{"sIndex":4,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 1 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":2}},{"sIndex":5,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 2 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":3}},{"sIndex":6,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 2 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":4}},{"sIndex":7,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 3 BaseDB","dYear":"2009","dId":5}},{"sIndex":8,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 3 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":6}},{"sIndex":9,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 3 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":7}},{"sIndex":10,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 4 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":8}},{"sIndex":11,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 4 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":9}},{"sIndex":12,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 5 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":10}},{"sIndex":13,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 5 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":11}},{"sIndex":14,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2010] Scenario 6 DB","dYear":"2010","dId":12}},{"sIndex":15,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2010] Scenario 6 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2010","dId":13}},{"sIndex":16,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 7 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":14}},{"sIndex":17,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 7 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":15}},{"sIndex":18,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 8 BaseDB","dYear":"2009","dId":16}},{"sIndex":19,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 8 DB","dYear":"2009","dId":17}},{"sIndex":20,"sItem":{"cName":"ABC Partners","cId":0,"pName":"[ABC] ABC Partners","pTick":"ABC","pId":0,"dName":"[2009] Scenario 8 ExpResults DB","dYear":"2009","dId":18}}]

  function search(val) {
    val = val.split(' ');
    var filtered = arr.filter(function(item) {
      var found = [];
      for (var prop in item.sItem) {
        if (typeof item.sItem[prop] === 'string') {
          for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            if (item.sItem[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(val[i].toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
              found[i] = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return found.filter(function(expr) { return expr; }).length == val.length;
    });
    
    return filtered.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.sItem.dName > a.sItem.dName;
    });
  }
})(document);
```

```css
result {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: Courier New;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" />
<result></result>
```

Comment: Thanks for the function it provides a lot of clarity and currently working quite nicely. However, when I search for "2009", "2010" is also returned. Advice? I have a dataset with pYear 2010 and 2009.

Comment: @XiaoKan edit your question with those values too, so I can test them here and see what's going on. And, please, if my answer was useful for you, even if it's not exactly what you need, you can at least upvote it :)

Comment: sorry I tried to upvote but still a newb to this site and would not let me. However, I will make sure this gets upvoted :). Thanks!

Comment: @XiaoKan That was happening, because I was creating the `found` array outside the `filter` method, and then it was keeping its value through the other iteration. I've changed its place to inside the method, and everything is working fine now! I've edited my answer, so you can check it! Please, if it's useful for you, you can mark the answer as the accepted one. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much. This works wonderfully. I have marked my answer accepted. I have one more request. Instead of me sorting the returned array outside of that function. Is it possible to sort the array by dName descending within that array before it gets returned? Your help has been invaluable!